# Debugging stored procedures in Visual Studio 2008 Pro

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to setup debugging of stored procedures in VS 2008 Pro, when I right-click on the connection in the Server Explorer I don't see the **Allow SQL CLR Debugging** option at all.  The SQL Server is remote and running the 2005 express edition, so I'm not sure if I have to enable something on the remote server itself.  Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Followed instructions to setup Remote Debugging from this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

I still cannot get the option to step into a stored procedure when I right-click under the connection in Server Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial looks promising, haven't tried it, but will experiment and mark this question as answered once I verify it working.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102846/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051607-1.aspx